# If R[X] isomorphic to S[X] then R isomorphic to S?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I have the following problem:

> If $R[X]$ is isomorphic to $S[X]$ then $R$ is isomorphic to $S$.

I think this conjecture is false, however I haven't been able to provide a counterexample. Any ideas :( ? Thanks!